# Numpy: Construct Slice A La Carte

Tags: numpy

Suppose I have the following:

```
# in pseudo code

# function input 1
chord = [0,1,17,35,47,0]
dims = [0,1,2,4,5,6]
x_axis = 3
t_axis = 7

# what I'd like to return
np.squeeze(arr[0,1,17,:,35,47,0,:])

# function input 2
chord = [0,3,4,5,6,7]
dims = [0,2,3,4,5,6]
x_axis = 1
t_axis = 7

# desired return
np.squeeze(arr[0,:,3,4,5,6,7,:])
```

How do I construct these `numpy` slices given input that I can arbitrarily specify a pair of axes and a `chord` coordinate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented a reflection-based solution:

```
def reflection_window(arr:np.ndarray,chord:list,dim0,dim1):
    var = "arr"
    bra = "["
    ket = "]"
    coord = [str(i) for int(i) in chord]
    coord.insert(dim0,':')
    coord.insert(dim1,':')
    chordstr = ','.join(coord)
    slicer = var+bra+chordstr+ket
    return eval(slicer)
```

Staying native to `numpy` is probably better, but since python is a shell scripting language, it probably makes sense to treat it that way if necessary.

Comment: You could construct a similar list from the numbers and `slice(None)` objects, e.g. `slicer = [0,1,17,slice(None),35,47,0,slice(None)]]`.  Then slice with  `arr[tuple(slicer)]`.   In other words, `arr[1,2,3]` is the same as `arr[(1,2,3)]`.